# csv row rearrangement and also preserve value order, python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

[Current csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhDce.png)

Would like make a new csv file that looks like this:

[Desired csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6ySk.png)

My first thoughts are to:

```
r1= []
r2 = []
with open('loadba1.csv', "r") as csv_file:
       
      data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
             f or rows in data:
               r1.append(rows[0])
               r2.append(rows[1])
```

`r1 will give - TRUE`

`r2 will give - 'L_602356450160818331', 'wan1'`

Then loop through again r2 to pull out each value and 'somehow' combine.

I also cannot loose the value relationship e.g. TRUE - wan1  - L_602356450160818331

I am not sure of the approach I should take. Please advise.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the data as text rather than images.

Comment: How do you know when a new item is starting - is it always going to be two rows, or do you need to combine all rows that have an empty first column?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is use a manual `while` loop rather than `for`:

```
with open('loadba1.csv', "r") as csv_file:
    data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    while True:
        try:
            load_bal, interface = next(data)
        except StopIteration:
            break  # end of file
        try:
            _, the_id = next(data)
        except StopIteration:
            raise ValueError("No ID row for %s" % interface)

        ... # write out (load_bal, interface, the_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.Dataframe("csv1.csv", index = False)
result = []
Id, LoadBal, Interface = "","",""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for col, val in row.iteritems():
        if col == 0 and val:
            LoadBal = val
        elif LoadBal:
            Interface = val
            result.append({"LoadBal": LoadBal, "Interface": Interface,"Id": Id })
            Id, LoadBal, Interface = "","",""
        elif col!=0:
            Id = val
result = pd.DataFrame(result)
result.to_csv("csv2.csv")
```